# break out of a for loop and re-do it with updated list

Tags: python, for-loop, appendchild

This is my code:

```
for parseparent in allgroups:
  for groupPerm in self.permissions["groups"][parseparent]["permissions"]:
    if self.permissions["groups"][parseparent]["permissions"][groupPerm] and (groupPerm not in allgroups):
      allgroups.append(group)
      print("found a child- shall we do again?")
```

Firstly `self.permissions["groups"][parseparent]["permissions"]` will be a boolean value, thus my if statement is really reading like "If True and (groupPerm not in allgroups):".  Normally the permission will not exist unless it is true, but sometimes they *are* set to False.

My problem is that if we reach the print statement, I need to re-run this loop because all groups will now have a new member of the list.  There is no pre-defined limit of how far nested these could be, so I can't just do a set number of iterations like a range.

My solution is that when I get to `print("found a child- shall we do again?")`, i need to jump back to and re-do `for parseparent in allgroups:`.  I thought about list comprehension, but I don't know how to do that in this case.  most of the examples seem to be for a known, set amount of iterations.

basically, I suppose I am building lists from several dictionaries.  here is an example, but only two levels deep (could be more):

```
allgroups starts out as []
master list = [dict1]
dict1 = {"dict2": True, "item1": True, "item2": False}
dict2 = {"dict3": True, "item4": True, "item5": False}
dict3 = {"Other": True, "item6": True, "item7": False}
dict4 = {"item9": False, "item8": True, "itemz": True}
```

once done, `allgroups` should contain `[dict1, dict2, item1, dict3, item4, Other, item6]` - ideally, I really want it to just contain the `dictx` items (`[dict1, dict2, dict3]`), but... this will server my purposes for now.

In a nutshell... start with the parent list, see if one of the items is another list (the child), then see if that child, in turn, has children; until no more subchildren are found.

Comment: very confusing. When you say `dict1`, for example, do you mean `"dict1"` (i.e. the key in the dictionary) or `dict1` (i.e. the dictionary itself)?

Comment: maybe I'll explain the bigger picture: 
i have groups of "permissions".  but I want a group to be able to inherit another group.. so group "member" might contain "hello", "kitty" and "guest".  another group called "guest" might contain "home", "facts", "fun".
If person A has group guest, he has permissions "home", "facts", "fun".  however, person b with group "member" will have  "hello", "kitty" and all "guest" permissions since it has a permission called "guest"

Comment: I might have meant the key...

Comment: I welcome better ways to accomplish my objective :)

Comment: It would help a lot if you refactored your code to not use variable names that are also strings.

Comment: Also, do you know about [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)?  That's how you do an operation for nested layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while loop like that:

```
itemsToProcess = allgroups[:]
while len(itemsToProcess) > 0:        
    parseparent = itemsToProcess.pop(0)
    for groupPerm in self.permissions["groups"][parseparent]["permissions"]:
        if self.permissions["groups"][parseparent]["permissions"][groupPerm] and (groupPerm not in allgroups):
            allgroups.append(groupPerm)
            itemsToProcess.append(groupPerm)
            print("found a child- shall we do again?")
```

Comment: This one works great! except for small error: these - `allgroups.append(group)` should be 
`allgroups.append(groupPerm)`
`itemsToProcess.append(groupPerm)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is best addressed with a recursive generator. I'm sorry I don't one hundred per cent understand your structure, but consider the following:

```
def recurse_yield(d):
    yield d
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if v:
            recurse_yield(k)

d1 = {"hey": False}
d2 = {d1: True}

for k in recurse_yield(d2):
    print k
```

I've done my best to structure it similar to your problem, though e.g.the use of strings that matched actual variables confused me. But the main point is the use of a recursive generator to elegantly traverse the nested structure, hope that helps.

Comment: You may be right about this and I appreciate your effort to change the variables to ones more meaningful to my application.  Most all of the recursive explanations out there seem to deal primarily with sets of numbers.  I did up-vote your answer, however, unfortunately, I don't understand how it works well enough at this time, so I went with the more simple answer by @Eric Levieil